# VMware ESXi 5.5 possible in-band interface

Tags: vmware-esxi

I wish to create a private network in VMWare ESXi 5.5 that would allow a dedicated in-band interface between a guest and the hypervisor. We can then use that in-band interface to run pyvmomi to interact with the hypervisor. Coming from a Linux KVM environment, this can be easily accomplished, but I am not sure that this can be done on VMware. I am also curious if there is an "in-band" interface, for guests to interact with the hypervisor via open-vm-tools.

I have evaluated the following options:

1) Creating a private network on ESXi, but I can not configure VSphere to participate in a private network without using a dedicated physical interface. 
2) Evaluating ESXi API's, every call is dependent on the IP address of the VM. I can't seem to find any methods via an internal interface that would return the network address of ESXi and or the routing table of the virtual switch.

Comment: I attempted to create a private network, but VMware does not allow VSphere to be participate in it.

Comment: I could do a network scan for VMware ESXi instances, but how would I know that the VMware IP is indeed that the hypervisor that I'm running the guest on? I would try to login and find out, but that would be rather intrusive.

Comment: Can you update the question to show what your tried to do with the private network attempt?